# How to get File object from assets?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a markdown file in my assets folder. I am using a markdown viewer which takes `java.io.File` Object as an argument to parse the file on screen.

But i don't know how to get a File Object from a file in assets folder.
Is there a way i can achieve this. I tried URI way but it failed.

This is my code snippet which may help

```
val markDown = File("file:///asset/GalacticAstronomy.md")
        if (markDown.exists()) {
            Toast.makeText(baseContext, "File exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        } else Toast
            .makeText(baseContext, "File doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                MarkDown(
                    file = markDown,
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                )
            }
        }
```

**I am not trying to read the file, So using `assets.open("file")` isn't going to work**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i don't know how to get a File Object from a file in assets folder

That is not possible, as it is not a file.

> I am not trying to read the file, So using assets.open("file") isn't going to work

You do not have a choice. Either:

- Use a better markdown library, one that accepts an `InputStream`, or
- Copy the asset to a file yourself (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) using `assets.open()`), then use the resulting file with your existing library

Comment: i don't get your 2nd point. I am very new to Android development so a little more explaination will help or a resource where i can look for that particular thing

Comment: @tycoon: Copying data from a stream to a file should be covered in just about any book on Java programming. I cover Android filesystem access in [this chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack). I specifically demonstrate copying an asset to a file in [this section](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-files-005.html) of that chapter.

Comment: Oh sorry i know how to copy data from a stream i thought you wanted to say something different. Thanks for the help again.